# @import directive in R - which file and where in that file should we put this?

Tags: r

I understand that while creating an R package, we can export a function, by using an @export directive just above that function.

My query is about the @import directive.

Suppose I have 10 R files and 5 R functions in each of those R file. My query is : which R file and where in that R file should I put the @import directive.

As far as I can see it should not matter as to where I put the @import directive.

Answer (score 0):

The `@export` and `@import` directives are not part of R, they are interpreted by functions in the `roxygen2` package.  It translates them into appropriate entries in the `NAMESPACE` file.

Since they are not executable, it doesn't matter where you put them.  However, the documentation in `vignette("namespace", package = "roxygen2")` suggests that you should usually avoid the `@import` directive:  put the package name in the `Imports:` field in your `DESCRIPTION` file, and call functions in the form `pkg::fun()`.